# In a specific blog, the K2 theme does not have a Text Widget

Tags: themes, widgets

I have a WPMu installation on a closed network, and one blog is using the K2 theme, but the Text Widget is not offered as an option.  When I switch the theme to Default, the Text Widget is offered.  If I use K2 on another blog in the installation, I can see the Text widget.  Any ideas on why the Text Widget won't work on K2 on this specific blog?

Comment: Try disabling all plug-ins on that specific blog.  One or more might be interfering with K2.

Comment: I tried that, no luck :(

Comment: Did you also disable all network-wide plugins as well as blog-specific plugins?

Answer (score 1):

A reason for this can be that the Widget configuration data (that is what is stored into the database) is mixed-up on that certain blog. Those cases are hard to debug. What you can try is to reset all widget settings on that blog. Sometimes it's enough to remove the Text-Widget from the lower pane if it is available there. If not, remove the widget configuration from the database (backup first!). After that, the Text-Widget should be offered again.

Another problem could be something related to javascript. That's just a guess, but to play safe here, just disable javascript in your browser and then use the widget screen. It has a new design as it offerers now widget configuration in a non-js variant. You probably can setup the TextWidget here. So try this first even if you do not have a javascript problem.